# Updating database table through a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, forms, sql-update, froala

I'm creating a simple website with just two or three pages, and I'm using Froala editor to edit the content directly from the page. So I have a `<textarea>` within a form with the id of "edit" (To make it a wysiwyg editor) and a submit button.
So basically what I want it to do is to UPDATE the "body" column in the table "pages" (where the type = 1) in my database when the button is submitted...
Here's the code I have:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE type = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
```

And the html:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="edit" name="body"><?php echo $page["body"]; ?></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a action to your form and a method.

```
<form method="post" action="path/to/file-to-update.php">
   <textarea id="edit" name="body"><?php echo $page["body"]; ?></textarea>
   <button type="submit" class="button button-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Add code below to file-to-update.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE pages SET body = ? WHERE type = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si',$_POST[’body’], 1);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

You can read more about mysqli prepare statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or follow this [tutorial](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/)